# How do I copy the <options> from one select list, to another?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, html-select

I'm trying to copy the `<options>` HTML Codes from one select list to another. I have tested the script below, but it does not work.

I have tested with an 'alert' function, but it seems to only display the values within the previous options.

would anyone be able to recommend what I should use? Thank you!

```
$("select[name='NHIndexNo" + tablecounter + "_" + rowCount + "'] option").each(function(){
   $("select[name='NHIndexNo" + tablecounter + "_" + (rowCount+1) + "'] option").appendto($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Can you show your HTML as well?

Comment: `appendto($(this).val())`? that's `appendTo` and `$(this).val()` is not an element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**jQuery:**

```
$().ready(function() {  
     $('#add').click(function() {  
        return !$('#select1 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#select2');  
     });  
     $('#remove').click(function() {  
        return !$('#select2 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#select1');  
     });  
 });
```

**HTML:**

```
<div>  
  <select multiple id="select1">  
   <option value="1">Option 1</option>  
   <option value="2">Option 2</option>  
   <option value="3">Option 3</option>  
   <option value="4">Option 4</option>  
  </select>  
  <a href="#" id="add">add &gt;&gt;</a>  
</div>  
<div>  
  <select multiple id="select2"></select>  
  <a href="#" id="remove">&lt;&lt; remove</a>  
</div>
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/LbPAq/1

Comment: Just wondering, why do you have `.remove()` in there? In my tests it appears `.appendTo()` does that anyway.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp The `.remove()` is there to remove the selected item from the first select box. The `.appendTo()` appends the item to the second select box.

Comment: Have you tried it *without* the `.remove()`? It still removes it.

Comment: You are correct. The main reason why that is the case is because `appendTo()` inserts the selector into the target container. If we were to use `.append()`, then we would need to use `.remove()`.

Answer (score 6):

Simply try - http://jsfiddle.net/zDFdX/

```
   $("#stwo").html( $("#sone").html() );
```

HTML

```
    <select id="sone">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>

    <select id="stwo">

    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("select[name='NHIndexNo" + tablecounter + "_" + rowCount + "'] option").each(function(){
   $("select[name='NHIndexNo" + tablecounter + "_" + (rowCount+1) + "']").append($(this).clone());
});
```

You had it almost right

Answer (score 0):

Clone the elements before you append them to the other select element:

```
$("select[name='NHIndexNo" + tablecounter + "_" + rowCount + "'] option")
 .clone() // <-- creates a copy of each selected element
 .appendTo("select[name='NHIndexNo" + tablecounter + "_" + (rowCount+1) + "']");
```

Since you don't provide any context information or markup, I assume that the selectors are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your HTML, and I'm therefore only able to *guess* that your selectors are working appropriately, I'd suggest:

```
$("select[name='NHIndexNo" + tablecounter + "_" + (rowCount+1) + "'] option").clone(true).appendTo($(this).val());
```

The idea is that you clone the elements (matching the selector) and then append the *clone* to the other `select` element.

Note, also, that I've passed `true` (the `withDataAndEvents` parameter) into the `clone()` method; this is to copy across the data and events allocated to those elements with jQuery. Omit this parameter if you're not concerned about those being cloned.

References:

- [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).